# How to set Dynamic Connectionstring in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am developing an application and that there is an option to set a connection string based on the BaseURL.
Eg: If my URL is .com then from one default DB's table it will get the whole connection string and work the whole site based on that also same for all other sites.

I am using Entity Framework Core to get data and post data to the appropriate server but I am unable to configure that basically, I have a concept of using my product as a service for other applications so I have to give an iframe with that UniqueID and in DB it stores the connection string for that application.

When the user wants to access from an iFrame then it is easily accessed to their DB and their features that developed in our product.

I tried to configure the DbContext **OnConfiguring** method but it gives me an exception in the program file for use before initialization.

Technology: .Net Core(v5.0), Entity Framework Core

If anyone has an idea about this then please let me know it helps me a lot.

Comment: Chec out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823734/5298150

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abdusco I have checked your suggested post but as I mentioned I have got a connection string based on the user's iframe path in the path it contains one generated token for that application so it gets in DB and have to set that for DBContext and work regarding that.

Comment: You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to the factory mentioned in the answer I've posted and change the connection string depending on the path of the current request. I can post an answer if you'd like

Comment: @abdusco I have checked and apply your solution in my project and it works for me but on the iFrame, it shows me a migration page if I update then it affects my new database.

Comment: You should to add the current code to your post.